# How do i keep the <th></th> in a fixed position? School work

Tags: html, css

Yep. The table. Like the title says, how do i keep the header in 1 spot while scroll down?

```
<div style="height:400px;overflow:auto;">

  <table width="221px" border="1" bordercolor="#000000" align="right">
    <th> New Special Offers</th>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="Stuff for website/Special Offers!_s01.gif" width="221" height="203" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="Stuff for website/Special Offers!_s02.gif" width="221" height="200" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="Stuff for website/Special Offers!_s03.gif" width="221" height="210" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="Stuff for website/Special Offers!_s04.gif" width="220" height="204" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="Stuff for website/Special Offers!_s05.gif" width="221" height="198" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="Stuff for website/Special Offers!_s06.gif" width="221" height="200" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: kindly refer https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/

Comment: just by the way, the `<th>` needs to be inside of a `<tr>`, ideally enclose the header and body in separate `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags as well.

Comment: kindly check this https://jsfiddle.net/s38qrxe6/